# Determine if a New MySQL record was created or instead just updated?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this PHP function below that Creates a new Project Task MySQL database record if one with the same ID does not exist already.

If one does already exist with the same ID, then it instead `UPDATES` the MySQL record.

This code has a lot of time invested into it as it is very important that the Task record's `date_modified` field is to ONLY be updated in the event that any of these 5 fields have changed to a new value!:
- name
- description
- status
- type
- priority

If all of these fields have the same value as the previous value when making an `UPDATE`, for example if the `sort_order` value is changed then it would **NOT** update the `date_modified` field!

It works great after lots of work crafting it to work just right.  I mention all this as it is important to not break this functionality!

Now this question is because this function can `CREATE` and `UPDATE` Task records in MySQL.

I now have the need to know when each of these events happens.

**If a new Task record is `CREATED` then I need to know that a new record was created.**

**If the Task record is simply `UPDATED` then I need to know that the record had already existed and was simply Updated.**

**Is there anyway to determine which of the 2 events happened with what I have?**

```
private function _addOrUpdateTaskRecord($taskId, $projectId, $created_by_user_id, $modified_user_id, $name, $description, $status, $priority, $type, $date_entered, $date_modified, $date_started, $date_completed, $date_due, $milestone_id, $assigned_user_id, $sort_order, $heading){

    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO
            $this->tasksDbTableName(task_id, project_id, created_by_user_id, modified_user_id, name, description, status, priority, type, date_entered, date_modified, date_started, date_completed, date_due, milestone_id, assigned_user_id, sort_order, heading)
        VALUES
            ('$taskId', '$projectId', '$created_by_user_id', '$modified_user_id', '$name', '$description', '$status', '$priority', '$type', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), '$date_started', '$date_completed', '$date_due', '$milestone_id', '$assigned_user_id', '$sort_order', '$heading')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            date_modified = (CASE
                WHEN name <> values(name)
                OR description <> values(description)
                OR status <> values(status)
                OR type <> values(type)
                OR priority <> values(priority)
                  THEN UTC_TIMESTAMP()
                  ELSE date_modified
            END),
            modified_user_id='$modified_user_id',
            name='$name',
            description='$description',
            status='$status',
            priority='$priority',
            type='$type',
            date_started='$date_started',
            date_completed='$date_completed',
            date_due='$date_due',
            milestone_id='$milestone_id',
            assigned_user_id='$assigned_user_id',
            sort_order='$sort_order',
            heading='$heading'";

    $insertOrUpdateTasks = $this->db->query($sql);

     return $insertOrUpdateTasks;

}
```

---

**Update**

I am adding my MySQL Triggers code here for others to see as it might help someone someday with similar issue, or myself so I don't end up posting a question I have a solution to again!

**Trigger to create an Event record when a Task is CREATED**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS project_task_new_event;
CREATE TRIGGER `project_task_new_event` AFTER INSERT ON `apoll_web_projects_tasks`
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO apoll_web_projects_events (event_type, project_id, task_id, created_by_user_id, description, date_created) VALUES ('6', NEW.project_id, NEW.task_id, NEW.modified_user_id, NEW.name, UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

**Trigger to create an Event record when a Task is UPDATED**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS project_task_update_event;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `project_task_update_event` AFTER UPDATE ON `apoll_web_projects_tasks` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT (NEW.date_modified <=> OLD.date_modified)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO apoll_web_projects_events (event_type, project_id, task_id, created_by_user_id, description, date_created) VALUES ('7', NEW.project_id, NEW.task_id, NEW.modified_user_id, NEW.name, UTC_TIMESTAMP());
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is insecure. You have SQL Injection problem.

To know if the record was created or updated, simple compare if create_date != update_date

When you insert data, set create_date and update_date to the same value. In "ON DUPLICATE" section update "update_date" field.

Another solution is to use triggers, something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `update_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tasks_table` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        /* Add any fields you want to compare here */
        IF !(OLD.name <=> NEW.name OR OLD.description <=> NEW.description OR OLD.description <=> NEW.description OR OLD.status <=> NEW.status OR OLD.type <=> NEW.type OR OLD.priority <=> NEW.priority) THEN
           NEW.date_modified = NOW()
        END IF;
    END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to delete this question but it has answer already.  I just realized a couple months back I had already resolved this issue with the use of Triggers.  I actually have to use Triggers due to the fact that on 100 Task records, if a user changes the SOrt order of a single Task, it then would update 100 records instead of 1!  With my special SQL above and Triggers, I'm able to create a new Event record for just the 1 record that is changed out of the 100 that are "saved".  So as it is I have the solution.I will say your solution with Triggers is right on the money though so thanks!

Comment: I added my Triggers to the end of my question above for future reference too.  They are different from your example, I might look into these more but what I have seems to work pretty good for my needs so far.  You mentioned my SQL is insecure for SQL injection.  filter input ahead of time but I could also add this to the actual SQL query code...  `mysql_real_escape_string()` is that what you mean?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string - is a minimal thing that you need to do. In nowadays, best solution is to use "prepared statements" - this will make your code more secure and readable.

Comment: I agree, I generally use PDO, it is just hard to use it in a SugarCRM module =(

Answer (score 2):

You can use affected_rows from your db class. (I am uncertain what class that is exactly). From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the
>   affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row and 2
>   if an existing row is updated.

Comment: In my situation I am stuck using MySQL Triggers however this could still also be useful for other non-mysql events when an update vs create happens so thanks for sharing I will look into this!